# Flutter push notifications on background and terminated states working fine on AVD but not on physical device

Tags: android, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-virtual-device

The title pretty much says it all : I have this flutter application that is set to recieve push notifications, and does stuff with those messages.
It's associated to a Firebase Project and I manage the Remote Messages with the flutter package "Flutter Local Notifications"

Everything works fine when running the app in an AVD. But VERY OFTEN, when I run the app in my personnal smartphone, a physical device, I get the push notifications when the app is in foreground, but not when the app is in background or terminated ...
Those cases are covered by my code correctly because it all fully works on an AVD

Does anyone has ever encountered this behavior ? I feel like it must come from my mobile phone's configuration, but i cant determine what. Notifications are already enabled, so its not that ...

Yeah note that i'm working on windows with android devices (avd and physical)